# Joomla Blog Error: 0 - Invalid address:

Tags: joomla-3.5, update, configuration, error-pages

My blog has this error. The problem persits only on the pages that have articles on them. Please help!
[Udaipur - Blog](http://www.udaipurlakecity.com/blog)

> Error: 0 - Invalid address:   You may not be able to visit this page
>   because of:
>
> - an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
> - a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
> - a mistyped address
> - you have no access to this page
>
> The requested resource was not found.
>    An error has occurred while processing your request.

Comment: Nice to see you're using my extension :) I don't have the issue you mentioned though. Please try clearing your browser and Joomla cache, then refresh

Comment: If your issue is fixed consider to post back how your resolved it - or mark answers as accepted if there was one that solved it for you. Please also read the help section: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote, http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently updated to Joomla 3.5x and then the issue started? Have you checked that all your extensions are compatible with Joomla 3.5?

I would suggest to look in your extensions and disable any 3rd party that could look outdated.

Start with the plugins, you may have an old non-compatible content plugin installed for your articles. Not sure if you have noticed it, but all your articles give this error, not only the blog ones.